# Pass data between VBA and WPF dll

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, vba, dll

I've created a DLL from my WPF application and imported it into my Access/VBA project.

I used these commands to create an instance of an object on my DLL and open a new windows containing it:

```
Dim tst As New DllName.ClassName
    tst.ShowDialog
```

And this is working correctly: my window is created and shown correctly. My next goal is to open a VBA window from the created window.

I'll be more specific: I have a Button on my WPF-DLL and I want to open an Access Form.

The question is: is that possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by myself this way:

**My c# class with a button inside (WPF) contains:**

Delegate declaration:

```
public delegate void MyEventHandler();
```

Event interface:

```
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[Guid("***your-guid***")]
public interface _DllAppEvents
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void MyEvent();
}
```

My window class that MUST NOT IMPLEMENT the interface and contains my button:

```
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(_DllAppEvents))]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[Guid("C7FA28F7-7A8D-45BA-9F0B-2C6CD8FB8650")]
[ProgId("TestDll.Test")]
public partial class DllApp : Window
{
    // my event
    public event MyEventHandler MyEvent;

    // button event
    void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // call the event
        MyEvent();
    }
}
```

(note: I used namespace DllApp)

**My VBA code where i've imported the tlb contains:**

Global variable that must support events:

```
Public WithEvents X As DllApp.DllApp
```

I create the WPF window using a button on my Access Form:

```
Private Sub New_Click()
    Dim A As Object
    Set A = New DllApp.DllApp 
    Set X = A
End Sub
```

And i catch my events adding this method:

```
Private Sub X_MyEvent()
    MsgBox "button is clicked!"
End Sub
```

Where the name of the method must be Variable Name + _ + event name (in this case X + _ + MyEvent()).

Hope this can help.

(I'd like to know why my question was downvoted....bah)